# Monogame publishing with ClickOnce doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame, publishing

As title says, i have completed my first project in monogame after like 2 weeks of working pretty hard on it, and now after i published it, it doesn't work. I can't run the setup file that I got when i published game and I cant debug it in VS2015CE anymore.

When I run setup and try to install published version it says:

```
Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted. Contact the application vendor for assistance
```

And when i try to debug the game it throws

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Value cannot be null
```

I've seen [this topic](http://community.monogame.net/t/fixed-after-publishing-in-3-6-the-installer-doesnt-run-and-debugging-it-throws-a-new-error/8634) and he had basically same error like me but the problem is he fixed it by installing latest version of .Net, which i've done too but it sadly doesn't fix the problem for me.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
When I click "Details" button when message pops up on i get all this inside a notepad

```
   PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/Coppy/Documents/visual%20studio%202015/Projects/Game2/Game2/publish/Frogger.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Frogger.application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c233c28f0ad663b, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\Coppy\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Game2\Game2\publish\Frogger.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Users/Coppy/Documents/visual%20studio%202015/Projects/Game2/Game2/publish/Application%20Files/Frogger_1_0_0_0/Frogger.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
            -HRESULT:   0x8007001f
             Start line:    0
             Start column:  0
             Host file:     
        + Ena od naprav, priključenih na sistem, ne deluje. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [5.4.2017 21:48:49] : Activation of C:\Users\Coppy\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Game2\Game2\publish\Frogger.application has started.
    * [5.4.2017 21:48:49] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [5.4.2017 21:48:49] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [5.4.2017 21:48:49] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Users/Coppy/Documents/visual%20studio%202015/Projects/Game2/Game2/publish/Application%20Files/Frogger_1_0_0_0/Frogger.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
            -HRESULT:   0x8007001f
             Start line:    0
             Start column:  0
             Host file:     
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - Ena od naprav, priključenih na sistem, ne deluje. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: The latest one 4.6.2.

Comment: The message that pops up should have a "Details" button, click that and paste the result.

Comment: Here, i've just edited the post and posted results in the thread

Comment: What are your publishing settings? (location, installation folder, install mode)

Comment: Location - publish\                                                                          
                               Installation Folder - None                                                    Install mode - The application is available offline as well